# Get mailitem's completion datetime

Tags: c#, outlook

When you mark a message for follow-up in Outlook it gets a red flag. When you mark it again the flag changes to a tick sign and the task completion time shows up. How to get/set this time from a C# application?

I've tried using the mailitem's `TaskCompletedDate` but it returns only the date (not the time). I've also tried to find a task assigned to the marked message but didn't manage either. What am I doing wrong? Where should I look for it?

I'm using Outlook 2007 and 2010.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. I still don't know where Outlook keeps the taksitem related to the given message but I'm using Outlook Tables to display the necessary data. A table can retrieve the desired data for me and then I retrieve it from the table's cell.

The code that helped me get to this is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184632.aspx

The column (cell) where the completion date is stored is called "Flag Completed Date". It displays the whole datetime value, not only the date.

The downside to this method is that you still don't have direct access to that value and you cannot set it, only get it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the actual property you require, but most of the mailitems properties and methods are documented on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210946(v=office.11).aspx

Note: be sure to check which version of Outlook you are targeting. There are additional properties for 2007+.

EDIT

According to MSDN, this property is indeed a `DateTime`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.taskcompleteddate.aspx

As to why its only remembering the Date part i cannot explain. FYI I beleive the `TaskCompleteDate` is UTC.

Comment: I've updated my post with the info on the Outlook versions. I've searched the MailItem members already and I've tried the most obvious ones and it didn't work. As mentioned, the closest one is `TaskCompletedDate()` but it seems to return only the date but not the time. Any other ideas where the FlagCompleteDate is hidden?

Comment: "As to why its only remembering the Date part i cannot explain" - but it has to store the time somewhere because Outlook is able to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mailItems `propertyAccessor`.

To get:

```
myMailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10910040")
```

To set (using its sent date as example):

```
call myMailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10910040",myMailItem.PropertyAccessor.LocalTimeToUTC(myMailItem.SentOn))
```

Comment: I think I tried that and I think it didn't work. Did you test this?

Comment: Yes, i tested it. Note that I'm using it on my sent-folder.