# How to get the completion time of a task in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've written a VBA macro that exports in excel all completed (ticked)  mails from a mailbox based upon the TaskCompletedDate property. However TaskCompletedDate shows only the date portion of the DateTime value. Is there a way to getthe time value as well?

I'm using Outlook 2010.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10259285/2258

Comment: Not really, because the Flag Completed Date can be manually changed by the user and I need to access the system completion time for reporting purposes.

Comment: I've added an answer to stackoverflow.com/a/10259285/2258

Answer (score 0):

Documentation reads that it returns Date type, so you can't get exact time I'm affraid, unless you save it on your own in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that - Outlook only stores the date (in the UTC time zone). You can see the data on the MAPI level in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - select the task, click IMessage button).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get the time as well. For this first go to your outlook express mailbox. Then right click on the column header and select "View Settings". Now in the pop-up window click "Format Columns". Now select the "Flag Completed Date" column on the left hand side and then from the format drop down select the 1st, 2nd or 3rd option. Click ok and come out of settings.

Now whenever you extract the info from the taskcompleteddate property you will get the time as well.

I am too late to answer... i have joined recently. But I hope this will help someone else who might be looking for it.

Regards,
Premanshu

Comment: "outlook express"? No matter what setting you use in the view, the data is simply not there. Outlook does not preserve the time portion. Look at the data in OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI.